# Get ads performace data using facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an ETL that will:

- Get data using some **Facebook API**
- Retrive clicks, impressions and money spend by each ad and each day
- Load that data into a SQL database

I was able to do that but I belive that the solution is not really eficient. It takes a lot of time to retrive very few data (3000 rows takes me around 3 minutes).

What I did was:

- Use [Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/) and query by **ad**
- Using field expansion retrive **insights** of the ads

An example of the **html GET request** would be:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_<account_id>/ads?fields=insights.time_increment%281%29.date_preset%28last_7d%29%7Bad_id%2Cclicks%2Cimpressions%2Cspend%7D&limit=300`

This requests has:

```
params = {
    'fields': 'insights.time_increment(1).date_preset(last_7d){ad_id,clicks,impressions,spend}',
    'limit': 300
}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer XXX"} #(where XXX is the token)
```

Is there a **better API** or **endpoint** to retrive that data?

Comment: So you are making only one single request to get the data for all ads already? Then there’s probably not much that can be done to speed this up any further.

Comment: I am doing one request. But to avoid exceding time limits I use a limit (300 in this case) which makes me do 3-5 more requestes.